# how to push values from an array of objects to another array javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I am using React and I want to push data from an array of object to another empty array present in an object.
I want to push the data from the array `devices` to an empty array `devicesList`.
`devices` is logged like this on the console:

```
(2) [Device, Device]
0: Device {deviceName: 'AC', deviceStatus: 'off'}
1: Device {deviceName: 'TV', deviceStatus: 'off'}
```

I have a function that added on click the `devices`to the `devicesList`. I want that to each time I add a new device to the array `devices` it adds it by the push() method at the end of the `devicesList` array.
The problem is that when I am using `devicesList.push(devices)`the data are not added to the destination array per index. It is added like this:

```
devicesList: Array(3)
0: [] 
1: [Device]
Device {deviceName: 'Light', deviceStatus: 'off'}
2: (2) [Device, Device]
0: Device {deviceName: 'Light', deviceStatus: 'off'}
1: Device {deviceName: 'Stereo', deviceStatus: 'off'}
length: 3
```

How can I push the data from `devices` so the array `devicesList` looked rather like this :

```
devicesList: Array(3)
0: []
1: [Device]
Device {deviceName: 'Light', deviceStatus: 'off'}
2: [Device]
Device {deviceName: 'Stereo', deviceStatus: 'off'}
length: 3
```

Here is the code:

```
  
  const [showAdd, setShowAdd] = useState(false);
  
  const [deviceName,setDeviceName]=useState('')
  
  const [deviceStatus,setDeviceStatus]=useState('off')

  const [devices,setDevices]=useState([])
  
  


  const AddNewDevice=(deviceName,deviceStatus)=>{
    
        //1st step: Validation of the device:
    
    let containsStereo=devices.some(e => e.deviceName === 'Stereo')
    let isBathroom=currentRoom.roomType === 'Bathroom'

    let devicesList=currentRoom.devicesList

    if ((containsStereo&&deviceName=='Stereo')||(!isBathroom&&deviceName=='Boiler')||(devicesList.length>5)) return alert('error')
    else {
      
      //2nd if validated creation of new device

    const newDevice = new Device(deviceName, deviceStatus);
    console.log(newDevice); 

    setDevices([...devices,newDevice])
    console.log(devices);

    devicesList.push(devices);
  
    console.log(currentRoom);

  }

  return devicesList

  }
```

Comment: Do you want the 0th index of your devicesList array to be the empty array? Not sure why you would want that. Also what is the idea behind the representation of each element of your devicesList array being a one element array (except for the 0th which is an empty array).

Comment: No I dont want the 0th index of devicesList array to be the empty array. React renders it like that because of the asynchronous behavior (if I understood correctly). I prefer it to be fill with the first devices values added.

Comment: Secondly the idea behind having each element of devicesList array being a one element array is so that when the component is re-rendered and I want to add new devices, devicesList doesnt appear like this : ```devicesList: Array(3)
0: [] 
1: [Device]
Device {deviceName: 'Light', deviceStatus: 'off'}
2:  []
``` because at the end I want to display all the new devices added and not only the last ones after last component rerender. I dont know if iam clear in my explanations...I am sorry I hope it is understandable

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I really don't know what you want. You say you want this devicesList: Array(3)
0: []
1: [Device]
Device {deviceName: 'Light', deviceStatus: 'off'}
2: [Device]
Device {deviceName: 'Stereo', deviceStatus: 'off'}
length: 3, but that just means that the first element (the 0th index) is indeed an empty array

Comment: Yes I was not really clear in my question I was working on this all night so too tired to succeed explaining my self clearly Iam sorry...Finally I manage to simply push newDevice into devicesList and it allowed me to get exactly the result I wanted and with no empty array at the 0th index. Thank you very much any way !